# Pass variable in find_element Selenium Python through CSS_SELECTOR or XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, attributes

I am trying to pass a variable in *find_element* with **Selenium Python** but it returns *ElementNotInteractableException*.
The HTML I am trying to scrape looks like this and what I need is to pass a variable to *find_element* containing the attribute *data-code* and click it:

```
<div class="stations-columns">
   <span class="station-link" data-code="BC_">Bologna Centrale</span>
   <span class="station-link" data-code="SMN">Firenze S.M.Novella</span>
   <span class="station-link" data-code="LON">Lamezia Terme C</span>
   <span class="station-link" data-code="MRT">Maratea</span>
<div>
```

I am first trying to insert one single string but then I will make it loop through a list.
These are my trials both using CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH but none seem to work:

```
code = 'BC_'

# CSS_SELECTOR attempt:
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-code='" + code + "']").click()

# XPATH attempt:
xpath = f'.//span[@data-code=\'{code}\']'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath).click()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

Alternative:

Finding elements by CLASS_NAME seems to work out better but:

- it gives me the total list so it needs some parsing;
- because these elements are in a drop down menu scrolling till some of these elements is needed, as they could be hidden.

The following code works out somehow except when I try to make it scroll till element if exception is raised. How to adjust it?

```
# selecting the box to fill (it also seems to load the elements I want to find):
box_destino.click()

# finding elements and parsing them:
station_codes_tot_new = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'station-link')
station_codes_destino_new = []
for elem in range(len(station_codes_origine),len(station_codes_tot_new)):
    station_codes_destino_new.append(station_codes_tot_new[elem])

# trying to click a hidden element (in the drop down menu) but now returns 'MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException':
try:
    station_codes_destino_new[10].click()
except:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(station_codes_destino_new[10]).perform()
    station_codes_destino_new[10].click()
```

Comment: Can you post the url? Wondering if it's not visible to click or something.

Comment: You're trying to click on a `span` - these elements are normally something a user interacts with which is why you're getting notInteractable. Users typically click `links` or `buttons`. more info here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp   -  Are you sure you need to `click` this element?  Why not use  `.text` to just get the content?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan here is the URL: https://www.italotreno.it/it/destinazioni-orari/orari-treni

Comment: @RichEdwards they are elements of a drop down menu and I need to loop through clicking them one by one so to fill the related box and search for results.

Comment: Can you share more of your code and what you're trying to achieve on this page?  -  You won't be able to interact with the `BC_` element until you expand the menu. Looking at the site you need to click on `@id=departure-city_` first to open the popout, then probably a scroll into view (just like Arundeep says!) then probably need a sync, then you can  probably interact with your values.

Comment: @RichEdwards ok see edit please! :)

Comment: Debugging in the browser - it looks like this isn't accessible even with JS. The entire pop-out menu activates as a link no matter where you move the mouse.  It's probably possible, but with your current approach it's going to be high effort.  Take it up one step, without saying anything technical, as a user, what is your goal on this page?  - (for example) are you just trying to do a travel search - from Agropoli to Paola?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do several searches, exactly combine all the elements of the first box with all of the elements of the second box, search and scrape the results. Any alternative ideas?